# Align and anchor images in iOS layout (or swift)

Tags: ios, xcode, user-interface, swift, uiimageview

I have two images and I would like to align horizontally, but the second image, but the second image must be aligned and anchored at the bottom of the first image, I post a picture to understand it better.

[Picture here](http://postimg.org/image/ybktb97sr/)

I think there isn't method to do so via the xcode editor.

Thanks guys!

Edit: (I accidentally deleted my comment and I can not comment)

@Rory McKinnel I did it thanks, now the problem is when the screen has a different size, because the images get bigger but I can not change the offset value setted in the layout editor of xcode.
I have do this:

```
class TopRow: UITableViewCell { 
   @IBOutlet weak var imgTop: UIImageView!
   @IBOutlet weak var OffsetWhiteCircle: NSLayoutConstraint!
   @IBOutlet weak var imgWhiteCircle: UIImageView!  
   override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()  
        let heightImgWhite = imgWhiteCircle.frame.size.height
        let div = Float(heightImgWhite / -2)
        OffsetWhiteCircle.constant = CGFloat(div)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Align image 2 with image 1 centres horizontally.

Anchor the top edge of image 2 to be the bottom edge of image 1 with an offset equal to half the image 2 height. This will make image 2 show half way up from the bottom of image 1.

That should give you what you have in the diagram.

This relies on image 2 always having the same height. If the height of image 2 can change, you could link the offset constraint to an IBOutlet and set the offset in your code when you know the image size.

Comment: Thank you very much, now I'll try.
I'm new in iOS and in my opinion the editor of xcode, it isn't the top.
One last thing, to make the anchors must select both images right? and I need the constraints?

Comment: Move image 2 below image 1. Select image 2 on its own and select the constraint tool. Select the top constraint and use the top constraint menu to pick image 1 rather then the containing view.  Set the offset then click the add constraint button. The offset probably needs to be negative.